# Regex with no leading dot and maximum one leading zero

Tags: java, android, regex

How can I write a regular expression that matches a string with the following properties?:

1. Contains numbers as well as only dot which is decimal separator (But dot is not necessary which means it can be `123` or `123.4` or `123.56`).
2. No leading dot (Not `.12`).
3. Leading zero can be written only if it is followed by a dot (can not be like `000.12`, only `0.12`).
4. Have only 2 decimal places.

Comment: what about `123`?

Comment: @YCF_L sure, possible

Comment: Doesn't example in #3 (`0.123`) violate rule #4?

Comment: Title says "maximum one zero", but `100.05` has 3 zeroes and seems like it should be valid.

Comment: @Andreas yeah, you are right. I will change now

Comment: @Andreas, I meant maximum one leading zeros :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To the left of the decimal point you want a number (1 or more digits) that doesn't start with a zero:

`[1-9][0-9]*`

Or it can be just a zero:

`0|[1-9][0-9]*`

The value may have a decimal point and 1-2 digits after the decimal point:

`\.[0-9]{1,2}`

Left side is required. Decimal point and fractional digits are optional:

`(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?`

The first non-capturing group is needed to limit the scope of the `|` pattern. The second non-capturing group is needed to make combined "decimal point and fractional digit" pattern optional.

Note that this will allow trailing zeroes, e.g. `100.00`

---

Depending on preference, `[0-9]` can also be written as `\d`. I'd normally use `\d`, but since regex also has `[1-9]`, I liked `[0-9]` better here as I felt it helped clarify the difference.

Depending on how regex is used, you may need to add the `^` begin / `$` end anchors. They are needed when using `find()`, and are not needed when using `matches()` but don't hurt:

`^(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`

Answer (score 4):

Using negative look-ahead to ensure the string doesn't start with zero and another digit (but can be just zero, or zero followed by a dot)

`^(?!0\d)\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`

Explanation and sample: https://regex101.com/r/7ymqcn/1

P.S. Also more efficient than Andreas' answer (takes fewer steps to match)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The link you shared is very useful for understanding and checking regex.

Answer (score -1):

You could try converting the input string to *float* (that would take care of removing leading zeros and the dot without zero, as well adding ".00" if the input is only an integer, and you can set the maximum decimal numbers. If an exception is thrown at the conversion, the input doesn't match what you want. You can then convert the float back to string or keep it as a float value for calculation.

> See:
>   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)

Comment: OP is not asking to *fix* the input, but to *validate* it. --- Using `float` is a bad idea, since it has very low precision. At the very least, `double` would be better. `BigDecimal` would be even better, so there would never be a loss of precision.